# MySQL query to Join results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to have separate columns from the results of the query in which I take the start and end timestamp of two conditions `True` and `False`

My Query is like below

```
SELECT MIN(timestamp) AS start_false, 
       MAX(timestamp) AS stop_false, 
       isidle
FROM (
   SELECT timestamp, isidle,
          @grp := IF(@br = isidle, @grp,
                     IF(@br := isidle, @grp+1, @grp+1)) AS grp
   FROM `ActiveIdleTable` 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 0, @br := '') AS vars
   ORDER BY `timestamp`) AS t  WHERE `timestamp` LIKE  '2020-10-14 %' 
GROUP BY isidle, grp
```

The output is like below

```
"2020-10-14 15:52:18"   "2020-10-14 15:52:18"   "False"
"2020-10-14 17:34:16"   "2020-10-14 17:47:15"   "False"
"2020-10-14 17:53:15"   "2020-10-14 18:00:35"   "False"
"2020-10-14 18:18:14"   "2020-10-14 18:18:14"   "False"
"2020-10-14 10:11:12"   "2020-10-14 10:11:12"   "True"
"2020-10-14 10:19:12"   "2020-10-14 10:19:12"   "True"
"2020-10-14 10:33:11"   "2020-10-14 10:34:11"   "True"
```

My current result is correct as per the query. Now I am trying to make separate columns of `start_false` and `stop_false` for the results of both conditions like `True` and `False`.
I am trying to have this kind of column output and that `trying...` is since last two days and I have tried to do away with some PHP parsing of this output. It would be great to have some help on modifying the query and the grouping to include the columns like below.

```
start_true, stop_false, isidle , start_false, stop_false, isdle
```

My Table Structure and some data it contains

> column Name : timestamp
> type : tinytext

> column Name : isidle
> type : tinytext

```
"2020-07-28 11:05:51"  "False"  
"2020-07-28 11:06:51"  "False"  
"2020-07-28 11:08:12   "False"  
"2020-07-28 11:08:50"  "False"
"2020-07-28 11:09:51"  "True"   
"2020-07-28 11:11:11"  "False"
"2020-07-28 11:11:51"  "True"   
"2020-07-28 11:12:51"  "False"  
"2020-07-28 11:14:12"  "False"  
"2020-07-28 11:14:51"  "False"
"2020-07-28 11:15:51"  "False"  
"2020-07-28 11:16:50"  "True"   
"2020-07-28 11:17:51"  "False"
"2020-07-28 11:18:51"  "False"  
"2020-07-28 11:20:12"  "False"
```

Comment: Please provide your table structure and some sample data

Comment: Edited with table structure and some data.

Comment: Please look is it can help you: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7bd62472969af41079bfbb55e68cfd93&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: I am already getting this output. I am trying to make separate columns for start time,end time for True and separate columns of start time, end time for  False. Thank you